# How to fix "Class not found" Error for the Google Sheets API?

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I am trying to set up a website that has google sheets API functionality, due to the constraints of the hosting service, I installed the API on my local computer with Composer before uploading everything onto the site. However, when I try creating the Google_Service_Sheets object, it says that the class cannot be found.

I've tried recreating the autoload.php file, and also adding a seperate require function:

```php
require_once "./googleapi/google-api-php-client-2.2.3/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/Sheets.php";
```

Main code:

```php
require_once $configs["googleapifilev2"];
require_once "./googleapi/google-api-php-client-2.2.3/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/Sheets.php";
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName('test');
$client->setScopes([\Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setAuthConfig($configs["googlecredentials"]);
$service = new \Google_Service_Sheets($client);
```

autoload.php code:

```php
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit68a7a3a3b2a74c49476ad55dd7b1c990::getLoader();
```

An error occurs only when I call the Google_Service_Sheets object, but not the Google_Client.

Error message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Google_Service_Sheets_Resource_Spreadsheets' not found in /storage/ssd3/963/10211963/public_html/googleapi/google-api-php-client-2.2.3/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/Sheets.php:69
Stack trace:
#0 /storage/ssd3/963/10211963/public_html/twowvotingaction.php(56): Google_Service_Sheets->__construct(Object(Google_Client))
#1 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd3/963/10211963/public_html/googleapi/google-api-php-client-2.2.3/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/Sheets.php on line 69
```

(Related lines in the API sheets.php file):

```php
  public function __construct(Google_Client $client, $rootUrl = null)
  {
    parent::__construct($client);
    $this->rootUrl = $rootUrl ?: 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/';
    $this->servicePath = '';
    $this->batchPath = 'batch';
    $this->version = 'v4';
    $this->serviceName = 'sheets';

    $this->spreadsheets = new Google_Service_Sheets_Resource_Spreadsheets( //Line 69
        $this,
        $this->serviceName,
        'spreadsheets',
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, when uploading the files, I accidentally put the ./googleapi/google-api-php-client-2.2.3/vendor/google/apiclient-services/src/Google/Service/Sheets folder, which defines the class, in the wrong directory, I moved it, and it now works.